# Error connecting to an SQL data source when using sqlsrv_connect()

Tags: php, iis-7, php-5.3, sqlsrv

I'm fairly new to using PHP to connect to a SQL Database and I am having an issue where I receive this error message, when trying to connect to a database via `sqlsrv_connect()`:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I've followed the instructions [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296170.aspx) and have placed this extension; `php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll`, into the `php.ini` file. `Phpinfo()` shows `sqlsrv` as enabled on the web server but I still receive the same error when trying to connect to the data source.

Below is the code I am using:

```
$db_server = 'tcp:192.168.0.1';
$db_credentials = array('UID' => 'Domain\Username',      //SQL Server UID
                       'PWD' => 'Password',                 //SQL PW
                       'Database' => 'ThisDatabase',        //Name of the database
                       'CharacterSet' => 'UTF-8',
                       'ConnectionPooling' => 'False',  
                       'LoginTimeout' => 60);               //Number of Seconds before fail

$db_connect = sqlsrv_connect($db_server, $db_credentials);

//Check the connection to the SQL Database to see if it's valid or else display errors.
if ($db_connect === false) {
 die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
} else {
 echo "Success: Connected to database.";
};
```

I'm completely stumped, so any help will be useful!

Comment: Did you install the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server or SQL Server Native Client? Did you restart the Web server afterwards?  Be aware of the [sqlsrv_client_info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296165.aspx) function to check though it might not work if you haven't opened a connection.

Comment: @Terminus I've Installed `SQL Server Native Client 2012` on the SQL server and have also setup a System DSN in the Data Sources (ODBC) program. The web sever has been restarted, I've also checked `sqlsrv_client_info` as suggested, and received this message: "An invalid parameter was passed to sqlsrv_client_info."

Comment: @Terminus It appears that I installed the `SQL Server Native Client 2012` driver on the wrong server, I installed it on the SQL server not the web server. It's working now, Thank you!

Comment: glad you got it sorted out! And thanks for coming back and updating your question so that noone would run into a situation like [this](https://xkcd.com/979/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @Terminus, installing either the `SQL Server` driver or `SQL Native Client` driver on the web server resolves the problem.